# Removing an item if the quantity is 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a user updates the quantity of an item, I want to save the cart (so I can redirect to it) and destroy that line item.  I also want to check to make sure that there is enough inventory in stock of that item as well, if they were to increase the quantity.  So my update function looks like this (trust that the response functions work, as they seem to.  It cuts the code about in half so it's easier to view):

```
  def update
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item_new_qty = params[:item][:qty]
    unless LineItem.get_inventory_check?( @line_item.id , params[:item][:qty] )
      respond 'Insufficient Inventory'
    else
      if @line_item_new_qty == 0
        @line_item_cart = @line_item.cart
        @line_item.destroy
          respond 'Item Deleted'
      else    
        respond 'Quantity Updated'
      end
    end
  end
```

get_inventory_check seems to be working, if there is enough, it changes and saves the quantity of the line_item, and return true.  Otherwise, it strictly returns false.

I have tried putting the if == 0 statement in every spot possible, and the only thing that I can get to work is if I have @line_item.qty == 0, then it will delete it will first update it to 0, then if you try to update it from their deletes it.  I assume that means that it can't tell that the line_item has been updated in the get_inventory_check method, but using params in the if statement doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

More than likely, `params[:item][:qty]` is a `String` and therefore `@line_item_new_qty == 0` will return `false`. One way to potentially fix this is by converting `@line_item_new_qty` to an integer:

```
if @line_item_new_qty.to_i == 0
```

Alternatively you could just compare it to `"0"`, but in general, the problem is likely one of comparing different types.

Comment: Aha! Brilliant thanks!  I'll mark it as correct as soon as I can @Marc Baumbach

Comment: Still the best would be to do `@line_item_new_qty = params[:item][:qty].to_i` from the start so you don't have to care about it along the way.

Comment: @oldergod True, that's another place to fix it. The only concern I'd mention here in general with converting types is be mindful of cases like `params[:item][:qty]` not being passed in. It'll be `nil`. `nil.to_i` will be the same as `0`. So you just need to watch out for things like that which might catch you off guard.